# mac unix script problem

Tags: unix, scripting, awk

I'm trying to write a script that breaks up a VERY large file into smaller pieces that are then sent to a script that runs in the background. The motivation is that if the script is running in the background, I can run in parallel.

Here is my code, ./seq works just like the normal seq command (which mac doesn't have). and $1 is the huge file to be split.

```
echo "Splitting and Running Script"

for i in $(./seq 0 14000000 500000)
do
   awk ' { if (NR>='$i' && NR<'$(($i+500000))') { print $0 > "xPart'$i'" }  }' $1 
   python FastQ2Seq.py xPart$i &
done

wait

echo "Concatenating"

for k in *.out.seq
do
cat $k >> original.seq
done

for j in *.out.qul
do
cat $j >> original.qul
done

echo "Cleaning"
rm xPart*
```

My problem is that only xPart0 is made and it only has 499995 lines in it before the program hangs. I put some debugging echos in the script and I know the awk statement is what stops the script. I just can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `split -l 500000`?

Comment: Instead of `seq`, OS X has `jot`. Or, in Bash, `for ((i=0; i<=14000000; i+=500000))`

Comment: split is way too slow. My file is 3.6GB, split can't handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "Splitting and Running Script"
# splits to smaller files each 50000 lines, if i understand your problem correctly
awk 'NR%50000==1{++c}{print $0 > "xPart"c".txt"}' file
# or use split -l 50000 
for file in xPart*
do
    python FastQ2Seq.py "$file" &
done
echo "Concatenating"
cat *.out.seq >> original.seq
cat *.out.qul >> original.qul
```

Comment: This was really close. I ended up doing

awk '{if (NR%500000==1){++c}{print $0 > "xPart"c}}' $1

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) command --

> ```
>   split -- split a file into pieces
>
>   Output  fixed-size  pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default
>   size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is `x'.  With no INPUT, or  when
>   INPUT is -, read standard input.
> ```

Should be much faster, reliable, and cleaner than running awk in a loop!

Comment: Tch. At least point to the right man page :P http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/split.1.html

Answer (score 0):

If your seq truly works like the standard seq, you're calling it wrong.  The proper command line for seq is:

```
seq FIRST INCREMENT LAST
```

So you would need to change your seq commandline to:

```
seq 0 500000 14000000
```